# Azure SQL Database without an Azure App Service plan?

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database

I want to build a Xamarin.Forms app using only one Azure SQL Database.

My question is : is it possible to use an Azure database without an App Service subscription ? I just want to pay for the database (I have a small budget).

If it is, I was not able to find a proper tutorial describing how to connect to this database (all tutorial show how to use the database with App Service)

Thanks !

Comment: Yes, you can just create an SQL database in Azure.  But it is a horrible security practice to connect directly from a remote client to a db

Comment: Thank you for your response. So what is the best practice when you have a small budget ?

Comment: And is it possible to use Azure Cosmos without App Service ?

Comment: Jason is right - don't hit a database directly from a mobile app. If your budget is really tiny, consider Azure Functions to expose a HTTP endpoint that your mobile app can call. The Azure Function can then hit the database.